# ngFor show text visibility only on clicked input icon

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngfor

I have some keys which are loaded on the page using a forloop. The tokens should not be shown unless the specific visibility icon is shown. Previously, when I clicked any of the visibility icons all of the keys would show. I only want the key shown to be related to the icon clicked so I added and index but now all the keys are showing on page load and can no longer be toggled between visible and hidden.

**key.component.ts**

```
  hide: boolean = false;
  clickedIndex!: number;
```

**key.component.html**

```
<div ngClass="key-wrapper mt-5" *ngFor="let key of keyCopies, let i = index">
    <div class="key-card mb-4">
        <div class="left-col">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [readonly]="true" [type]="hide && clickedIndex ? 'password' : 'text'"
                    value="{{token.token}}">
                <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide; clickedIndex === i">
                    {{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}
                </mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
            <div><span>{{key.createdAt}}</span></div>
            <div>
                <button ngClass="btn-red" (click)="deleteUserKey(key._id)">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.Mac, you have two options

1. Only one element at time is "visibility" (you need one variable
   "clickedIndex")

   ```
   clickedIndex:number=-1  //declare one variable

   //use
   <div *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4];let i=index">
     <button (click)="clickedIndex=clickedIndex==i?-1:i">
            click</button>
      {{clickedIndex==i?'click':'no-click'}}
   </div>
   ```

   See that it's use the ternary operator "?" the ternary operator is
   only a "confortable" way to asign a value or another one to a
   variable

   ```
   if (condition)
      variable="successfully"
   else
      variable="not successfully"

   //can be translate like
   variable=(condition)?"successfully":"not successfully"
   ```

   When the button is clicked, the variable "clickedIndex" get the
   value of the index i or -1 is the variable has this value yet and
   show 'click' or 'no click' if "clickedIndex" get the value of the
   index i
2. Severals or none element at time are "visibility" (you need one
   array)

   ```
   hide:boolean[]=[]  //declare one array

   //use
   <div *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4];let i=index">
     <button (click)="hide[i]=!hide[i]">click</button>
      {{hide[i]?'click':'no-click'}}
   </div>
   ```

   See that "hide" is an array, (hide[0] is used in the first div,
   hide[1] in the second one, hide[2] in ...

I feel that you are mixing a bit the two concepts :(

Comment: thank you for this. I've tried both solutions but it only hides the text for the first input. I would like for all the inputs to be hidden until clicked one by one

Comment: @A.Mac, see a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1masly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html) I put the two cases

Comment: I'm interested in the second solution. If a value is added to the input you'll see that the value is showing with the visibility_off icon is showing when the value should infact be hidden