# Activate one input out of several in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input

I have several inputs, and a button on each input that enable this input, I want the behavior of the button to be like this: when I click below, it is enable, and when I click on another, only this input is enable and the other are disabled as the photo shows
[image: exemple]

How to do that?

Here is my code:

```js
public enable(index: number) {
  this.toggleInputs[index] = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" [disabled]="!toggleInputs[i]">
<button title="Modifier" (click)="enable(i)">EDIT</button>
```

Comment: sounds good what was the issue you encounter when you implemented it ?

Comment: Your code snippet has error.

Comment: It's looks like this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376991/ngfor-show-text-visibility-only-on-clicked-input-icon/73378445#73378445)

Comment: The other input does not disabled, when I click below both inputs are active,but i want it to behave like the picture above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public enable(index: number) {
  for (let i = 0; i < toggleInputs.length; i++) {
    toggleInputs[i] = false;
  }
  this.toggleInputs[index] = true;
}
```

Comment: Better use an unique variable

Comment: yes. ha has to refactor his code and provide an active class for inputs. but for this situation my answer is a solution.

Comment: @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili, `<input type="text" [disabled]="indexSelected==i"><button title="Modifier" (click)="indexSelected=i==indexSelected?-1:i">EDIT</button>` and declare `indexSelected:number=-1`